# How do I configure Keep-Alive in CXF or jaxrs:client

Tags: cxf, keep-alive

I'm using CXF and jaxrs:client to connect to a Restful service. However, the restful service timesout after 300 seconds - it's DDOS mitigation at their end. According to the owners of the Restful service, if we include a Keep-Alive header in oyr request, the timeout won't occur. How can I configure Keep-Alive in CXF or jaxrs:client calls?

Thanks in advance

Angus

Answer (score 0):

You can set a header for a `jaxrs:client` usign the `jaxrs:headers` tag

```
<jaxrs:client id="" serviceClass="" address="" inheritHeaders="true"> 
       <jaxrs:headers>
           <entry key="Connection" value="keep-alive"/>
       </jaxrs:headers>
</jaxrs:client>
```

Also you can configure timeouts in the `http-conf:client` tag of the `http:conduit` element

```
<http-conf:conduit name="*">
     <http-conf:client Connection="Keep-Alive"
                      ConnectionTimeout="0"
                      ReceiveTimeout="0" />
</http-conf:conduit>
```

The complete list of parameters is [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html). 
Note that `keep-alive` is the default. `ReceiveTimeout` **0** means no timeout. Default value is 30000 (30s)

Comment: It is possible that you have and additional timeout problem. Check the updated answer

Comment: Hi @angusrose, finally did you find a solution configuring timeouts?

Comment: Hi, yes, I eventually configured the jaxrs:client accordingly:<jaxrs:headers>
   <entry key="content-type" value="application/json" />
   <entry key="Connection" value="keep-alive" />
   <entry key="Keep-Alive" value="timeout=600000" />
  </jaxrs:headers>

Comment: Ok @angusrose, if this answer (or any other) fits your question, remember you can mark it as correct for future use and also it gives some reputation for you and me. It is not obligatory

Answer (score 0):

You can set the headers programatically like this:

```
  Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(serviceBean);
  Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
  headers.put("Connection", Arrays.asList("keep-alive"));
  headers.put("Keep-Alive", Arrays.asList("timeout=300"));
  client.getRequestContext().put(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS, headers);
```

Note also that Java 19 and higher has a new setting which allows you to override the client's keep-alive timeout, which defaults to 5 seconds.  To set it to 5 minutes, do this:

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive.time.server", "300");
```